# how to display the last added row in paginated google visualization table?

Tags: google-maps, pagination, google-visualization

At first, am not well-versed in language so sorry for that.

I am using google visualization table with pagination options.

```
this.draw = function() 
{
    this.table.draw(this.dT, {
        allowHtml: true, 
        showRowNumber: true, 
        cssClassNames: cssClass,
        page : 'enable',
        pageSize : 4,
        pagingSymbols: {
        prev: '&nbsp;&nbsp;<div align="center" style="width:50px;height:2px; text-align : center; font-size: 12px;">Previous</div>&nbsp;&nbsp;',
        next: '&nbsp;&nbsp;<div align="right" style="width:50px;height:2px; text-align : center; font-size: 12px;">Next</div>&nbsp;&nbsp;'
    }
    });
}
```

Whenever new row is added, the newly added row is selected using .SetSelection() but in UI it is showing from the first row in the table.

I need help to highlight/show the newly added row in table which is in page:2.

Thanks in advance.

i had included sample code...

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
google.load('visualization', '1', {packages: ['table']});
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
 var cssClass = {rowNumberCell: 'rowNumberCellClass'};

function drawVisualization() {
var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
data.addColumn('string', 'Name');
data.addColumn('string', 'Place');
data.addRows(4);
data.setCell(0, 0, 'John');
data.setCell(1, 0, 'Sam');
data.setCell(2, 0, 'Andreson');
data.setCell(3, 0, 'Cody');

data.setCell(0, 1, 'Stockholm');
data.setCell(1, 1, 'Dubai');   
data.setCell(2, 1, 'India');
data.setCell(3, 1, 'Australia');

visualization = new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById('table'));
//visualization.draw(data, null);
visualization.draw(data, {
        allowHtml: true, 
        showRowNumber: true, 
        cssClassNames: cssClass,
        page : 'enable',
        pageSize : 2,
        pagingSymbols: {
        prev: '&nbsp;&nbsp;<div align="center" style="width:50px;height:2px; text-align : center; font-size: 12px;">Previous</div>&nbsp;&nbsp;',
        next: '&nbsp;&nbsp;<div align="right" style="width:50px;height:2px; text-align : center; font-size: 12px;">Next</div>&nbsp;&nbsp;'
    },

    });

 }  
   google.setOnLoadCallback(drawVisualization);
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="table"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you provide a fiddle?

Comment: Thanks but Sorry I can't provide that

Comment: Hi.. I had included sample code.. Please go through this...

Comment: you can have the table start on a certain page with the `startPage` [option](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/table#configuration-options). if you need more help, please clarify your question, you mention `SetSelection` but i don't see it here.

Comment: Thanks for your idea.. I had gone through 'startPage' option and modified. Now it works great !!!